# Import-CSV does not preserve line indents

Tags: powershell

I am using `Import-CSV` to get the data from a csv file that looks like:

```
P1,1,3,4
   P2,4,5,6
   P3,1,2,3
      P4,8.7,6,3
```

I would like to keep the white-space in front of the text as it indicates the hierarchy. `Import-CSV` returns:

```
P1,1,3,4
P2,4,5,6
P3,1,2,3
P4,8.7,6,3
```

Is there a way to keep the white space?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data once it's been imported? You won't be able to query the imported data as the headers won't align, so importing to an array is pointless, maybe `Get-Content` is what you need to use...

Comment: Thanks, its working fine when the first column is something like "   P2", it can then preserve the space

Comment: Misunderstanding on alignment, thought you wanted `P2` to be imported into the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV isn't correctly formatted, the items in each row should all be quoted to meet the file specification:

```
"P1,"1","3","4"
"   P2,"4","5","6"
"   P3,"1","2","3"
"      P4,"8.7","6","3"
```

You can take a shortcut and only wrap the entries with leading spaces in quotes:

```
P1,1,3,4
"   P2",4,5,6
"   P3",1,2,3
"      P4",8.7,6,3
```

Then `Import-CSV` will function as you're expecting, headers added for demonstration:

```
Import-CSV leading_spaces.csv -Header "Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4"
```

Gives you your desired output:

```
Field1   Field2 Field3 Field4
------   ------ ------ ------
P1       1      3      4     
   P2    4      5      6     
   P3    1      2      3     
      P4 8.7    6      3
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [James C's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172292/import-csv-does-not-preserve-line-indents#comment85349867_49172292), you can do this with `Get-Content`:

```
$myData = Get-Content .\test2.txt

foreach($line in ($myData | Select-Object -Skip 1)){

    [array]$results += [pscustomobject]@{
        $myData[0].Split(",")[0] = $line.Split(",")[0]
        $myData[0].Split(",")[1] = $line.Split(",")[1]
        $myData[0].Split(",")[2] = $line.Split(",")[2]
        $myData[0].Split(",")[3] = $line.Split(",")[3]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, it will create a new object for each row:

```
get-content test.csv | % { 
    $row = New-Object PSObject                                       
    $i = 0
    $_ -split "," | %{
        $row | add-member Noteproperty "column$i" $_ 
        $i++
    }
    $row
}
```

Output will look like this:

```
column0             column1             column2             column3            
-------             -------             -------             -------            
P1                  1                   3                   4                  
   P2               4                   5                   6                  
   P3               1                   2                   3                  
      P4            8.7                 6                   3
```